# Replace switch statment where complex buisness rules are inside every switch statement

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have to calculate the price based on multiple input variables

```
public class Model
{
    public int Account { get; set; }
    public long Related{ get; set; }
    public int TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string detail{ get; set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }      
}
```

First switch starts with `TransactionType` . Based on `TransactionType` I need to use `Account,PlanId ,Related` fields for more information from database to get more information and some configurable information. There are more conditions based on those database values. Of coarse there are some common logic and information required between different `TransactionType`

now i can use

```
switch (TransactionType)
{
   case 1:
     //Check Related value and get more information from database
     //Apply buisness rule
     //Check PlanId value and get more information from database
     //Apply buisness rule
     //Get final value
     break;
   case 2
     //Check Related value and get more information from database
     //Apply buisness rule
     //Check PlanId value and get more information from database
     //Apply buisness rule
     //Get final value
     break;
   default:
     break;
}
```

Please help me how i can avoid these switch statements

Comment: Change the switch to an if? Use a different method? Use a dictionary? There are multiple ways to avoid a switch statement, this is far too broad for us to help you in any meaningful way

Comment: Someone with the same account already asked the same question... you may want to discuss that first to avoid such duplicated posts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your trying to do, but have you thought about creating a Transaction object to handle this? You could overload the constructor, or simply pass it the data, then have it handle all the sorting and gathering and spit back whatever you need. At that point you would only need an if statement to decide which constructor to call, or none at all if you are simply passing all the data you gathered.

For example: if you made a constructor that took all the variables you mentioned, you could then have the data sorted, rules gathered, database information retrieved all at object initialization. This would also allow you the option to manipulate that transition if you wanted after the object was made as well if needed.

Not sure if I am on the right track as to what you are looking for, but this was the first thing that popped into my head after reading your question.

Comment: Guys I ended up using chain of responsibility pattern